# File path as MVC route argument

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Part of my application maps resources stored in a number of locations onto web URLs like this:

```
http://servername/files/path/to/my/resource/
```

The resources location is modelled after file paths and as a result there can be an unlimited level of nesting. Is it possible to construct an MVC route that matches this so that I get the path in its entirety passed into my controller? Either as a single string or possibly as an params style array of strings.

I guess this requires a match on the files keyword, followed by some sort of wildcard. Though I have no idea if MVC supports this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A route like

```
"Files/{*path}"
```

will get the path as a single string. The `*` designates it as a wildcard mapping and it will consume the whole URL after `"Files/"`.

Comment: Does it work for physical files like `Files/abc/xyz.jpg`?

Answer (score 4):

For more information on ASP.NET's Routing feature, please see MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

And for the "catch-all" parameters you want to use, see the section under "Handling a Variable Number of Segments".