# ASP.NET MVC Catch All

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

The ignore route is defined like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Why not

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*}");
```

What is the significance of pathInfo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Exception will be thrown, route parameter must have name. The meaning of the * sign  is explained here [File path as MVC route argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323397/file-path-as-mvc-route-argument)

Answer (score 0):

That's just to give the route parameter a name or an exception will be thrown. You could have called it `{*foo}`.