# Get input with '/' character in url input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a upload center application using Asp.Net MVC 4. I want to have a url like this : `http://site.com/user/{username}/{path}` and path is like this`/dir1/subdir2/file.txt` and I return it(or edit it or etc)

but I don't know how can I allow to have `/` character in url? because Mvc throws a security exception. can anybody Help me?

**The directories aren't physical. I keep all files in one directory and save their's properties in DataBase**

Comment: You should use Query strings instead. Your url will be like this: `http://site.com/user/{username}/?path=/dir1/subdir2/file.txt`

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi I want it without query string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File path as MVC route argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323397/file-path-as-mvc-route-argument)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I searched a lot but I didn't find it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called "wildcard routing" (see duplicate [File path as MVC route argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323397/file-path-as-mvc-route-argument) for more info).

```
  "http://site.com/user/{username}/{*path}"
```