# MVC Wild Card route mapping not working on documents

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a page in my MVC site that is used to browse through a folder structure on the server, but the wild card mapping is not working for documents.

The mapping works for folder names such as

```
http://localhost:4321/Document/Folder/General_HR
```

Which maps to a shared drive folder like `T:\root\General_HR` in the controller.

But I get a 404 and the controller method isn't hit when trying to access a file such as

```
http://localhost:4321/Document/Folder/General_HR/Fire_Drill_Procedures.doc
```

Here is the route mapping

```
routes.MapRoute("Document Folder", 
    "Document/Folder/{*folderPath}", 
    new { controller = "Document", action = "Folder" });
```

I also have the standard MVC route that is applied after the one above:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I tried commenting out all other routes, but it still doesn't work.

I had had it working at one point, but I don't know what has changed since then. It seems that it's looking for a resource located at `C:\MyProject\General_HR` instead of being routed to the controller. How can I fix my mapping to account for this? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323460/526704) it should be working.

My controller method works like this: if the URL parameters contains an extension, then I `return File(filePath)`, otherwise I create a view model and return `View(viewModel)`. So when I click on something with an extension, it should still point to this same controller method and return the file.

```
    public virtual ActionResult Folder(string folderPath)
    {
        var actualFolderPath = folderPath;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(actualFolderPath))
        {
            actualFolderPath = DocumentPathHelper.RootFolder;
        }
        else
        {
            actualFolderPath = DocumentPathHelper.GetActualFileLocation(actualFolderPath);
        }

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(actualFolderPath))
        {
            return File(actualFolderPath, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(actualFolderPath));
        }

        var vm = new FolderViewModel();
        //build vm
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: What are your other routes that are defined, and in what order?

Comment: I've added the other route that I'm using that could conflict

Comment: Is this the only other route? Other routes that could possibly interfere would come before this one.

Comment: I commented out all other routes, the folder browsing still works but the document browsing still isn't working, so I don't think that it's other routes that are causing the problem

Comment: URLs with extensions, i.e. `*.doc` are not sent to the MVC routing framework, but rather are attempted to be served directly by IIS. See this article for a workaround: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works. It's geared to serve *.html through the MVC routing framework, but you can follow the same procedure for any file extension.

Comment: is there a way around that? or should I try to replace the `.` with a `_` or something?

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by altering my urls to the documents by replacing the `.` with a placeholder, then replacing it back in the controller.

for each item:

```
folderPath = folderPath.Replace(".", "___");
```

Then in the controller:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Folder(string folderPath)
    {
        var actualFolderPath = folderPath.Replace("___", ".");
```